# VBA Averageifs loop

Tags: vba, excel

I want to loop my averageifs in VBA:

1a

```
i = 1 To 12

Sheet5.Cells(i + 1, 10) = WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs(Sheet5.Range("B:B"), Sheet5.Range("Z:Z"), ????, Sheet5.Range("AA:AA"), "=2015")

Next i
```

So For the **????** I'm looking for a code that loops over 1 to 12, I already tried a lot of things and googled for hours.

Thanks for Your help.

---

Maybe this clarifies my problem:

1b

ps: first I was looking for a code that took the average over a month a and year, I already subdivided the dates into months and years and now I'm taking the average over a month in a certain year (e.g. february, 2016).

```
10/10/2015 ----- 13 

11/10/2015 ----- 9  

01/01/2016 ----- 2 

31/01/2016 ----- 3 

31/02/2016 ----- 4
```

So in this example if I want the average over January 2016, that should be 2,5. And I want to make a code that loops from 01/2015 till 12/2020 and puts the average in each cell.

Comment: You could do this with formula, then just use row() or rows() to get the number  something like sheet5.range("Z:Z"),row(z1)  or just use i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use row() or rows() to get the number something like `sheet5.range("Z:Z"),row(z1)` or just use i you'll also need to use month, if you are comparing to dates, so `month(z:z),i`  It can also be done with static formula

Comment: Can you clearify your answer, I'm not an expert in VBA. You do no have a formula that I can place on the **????**.

Comment: Just use I, as this is going from 1 to 12.  I've also put month(z:z),I in my answer

Comment: But when I use only i, I get an error  Unable to get the AverageIfs property of the Worksheetfunction class"

Comment: You'll need to add a helper column with month(z) in so AA1=month(z1) or you can use an array.  This would be easier in static formula

Comment: something like this `(SUM(--(MONTH($A$1:$A$7)=2)*($C$1:$C$7)))/SUM(--(MONTH($A$1:$A$7)=2))` could be used as a formula no need for code, my dates are in a1:a7 and my values in c1:c7